# How were elided vowels pronounced by the Romans?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation, elision

When I scan a verse, I simply leave out elided vowels: I don't pronounce them at all. But I've heard theories that the Romans did pronounce them, but just as very short vowels of half a syllable's length. What do we know about this? Is there consensus about the pronunciation?

Comment: I think they pronounced elided vowels as "vocales elisus"

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: Hmm I can't Google that, do you have more information? And hello!

Comment: It was a joke; as far as I can tell, that's the Latin phrase meaning "elided bowels". Also, hi!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is discussed in great detail in Allen’s classic [*Vox Latina* ch. 4](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aexkj_0oj3MC&pg=PA78&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false). His conclusion is (briefly) that a final short vowel followed by another vowel in the next word was elided (elisio), but a long vowel in the same position was reduced to a semivowel (synizesis).

Comment: Good answer! I have heard of *Vox Latina*, although I've never used it. Would you consider it authoritative? And did Allen seem certain about this, or was it more like an hypothesis?

Comment: Let us say that it has still not been replaced.

Comment: I'd agree with that. I've met experts who believe it's not right about everything, but as none of them has yet written a correction, he's the best to go with.